# Interactive Brokers Java API get all positions?

Tags: java, api, interactive, broker

I went through IB's java API and do not see any function for getting all current stock/option positions in my portfolio. What I am trying to do is: get all current/active positions in my portfolio ( positions may or may not sent from API ), then loop through the list to close the one that matches my criteria. Is there any way to do that?

thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Use the `reqAccountUpdates(true)` method to begin receiving events concerning the account. Then you get all positions through the `updatePortfolio()` event method. If you do not wish to subscribe to the account events periodically, call `reqAccountUpdates(false)` to end the subscription.

Comment: There is also this post on Linkedin which explains several details of account values handling: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/1001-tips-API-coding-Account-4932221.S.272145445?qid=fa8c9ad5-feda-4a7a-97f5-bd54552b6158&trk=groups_most_recent-0-b-ttl&goback=%2Egmr_4932221

Comment: @Jonas Hi, I cannot make it work. How do I implement the updatePortfolio() ? Do you have an example? (I am with Python, but I guess with Matlab I would be able to understand it too)